# UserControl Opacity Fade on Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

This has been addressed before, but I can't get it to work properly... should be very simple!

Here is my XAML:

```
<UserControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="UserControl">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Name="FadeOutAnimation">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                FillBehavior="Stop"
                                BeginTime="0:0:5" From="1.0" To="0.0"
                                Duration="0:0:1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                BeginTime="0:0:7">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Hidden</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
```

This works as expected: When the control's Visibility property is set to Visible, the control is displayed for 5 seconds, then fades over 1 second.  The control's Visibility is then reset to Hidden after 7 seconds (strange, but 6, the total time of the fade animation, was not sufficient - another MS bug I guess!).

Upon subsequent Button.Click events, the Visibility property appears frozen or locked to Hidden and is not able to become Visible again!

Any ideas why not?

Comment: Is it because the opacity is 0 after the storyboard?  toggling visibility won't be obvious if the opacity is still 0.

Comment: I set the FillBehavior to Stop. I have also tried to set the Opacity to 1.0 where I change the Visibility to 0. So that is not the problem, thanks anyway!

Comment: have you dug in with something like Snoop at runtime to figure out what's going on?

Comment: It appears that after an animation completes, the associated property cannot be changed in code.

Comment: well that seems rather odd.  as isn't the animation changing the value in *its* code?

Comment: Well, I have a code solution but StackOverflow will not let me answer my own question cause I'm new to the site and it is too long for a comment.  I'll post it when I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since properties set within the scope of an animation cannot be set without jumping through hoops as illustrated by the link LPL sent (which really helped btw!), I came up with a code behind solution rather than in XAML:

```
private void UserControl_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, 
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        DoubleAnimation fadeIn = new DoubleAnimation();
        fadeIn.From = 1d;
        fadeIn.To = 1d;
        fadeIn.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0));

        DoubleAnimation fade = new DoubleAnimation();
        fade.From = 1d;
        fade.To = 0d;
        fade.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(((MessageTextProperties)  
            DataContext).Duration);
        fade.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));

        NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());
        this.RegisterName(this.Name, this);

        Storyboard.SetTargetName(fadeIn, this.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeIn, new PropertyPath
            (UIElement.OpacityProperty));

        Storyboard.SetTargetName(fade, this.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fade, new PropertyPath
            (UIElement.OpacityProperty));

        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Children.Add(fadeIn);
        sb.Children.Add(fade);

        sb.Completed += new EventHandler(sb_Completed);
        sb.Begin(this);
    }
}

void sb_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

}

The trick is the sb_Completed. Since this *is* within the scope of the running animation, Visibility is able to be reset to Hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Does `FillBehavior="Stop"` in your ExitActions Storyboard help? 
I think this Storyboard holds the visibility value.

Take a look at [How to: Set a Property After Animating It with a Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

May be it will be useful for you also

```
void UControl_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
                DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
                da.From = 0;
                da.To = 1;
                da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                sb.Children.Add(da);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath(UserControl.OpacityProperty));
                Storyboard.SetTarget(da, this);
                sb.Completed += new EventHandler(sb_Completed);
                sb.Begin();
            }

            if (this.Visibility == Visibility.Hidden || this.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
            {
                Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
                DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
                da.From = 1;
                da.To = 0;
                da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                sb.Children.Add(da);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath(UserControl.OpacityProperty));
                Storyboard.SetTarget(da, this);
                sb.Completed += new EventHandler(sb_Completed);
                sb.Begin();
            }
        }

        void sb_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to animate Opacity (and optionally translate) using Transitionz attached properties ([Github](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.Wpf.UI/tree/master/SciChart.Wpf.UI.Transitionz), [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SciChart.Wpf.UI.Transitionz/))

As a simple example project, use the following code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication15.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:tz="http://schemas.abtsoftware.co.uk/transitionz"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2vc"></BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox" Content="Is Visible?" IsChecked="False"></CheckBox>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello World!" FontSize="44" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Visibility="Collapsed"
            tz:Transitionz.Opacity="{tz:OpacityParams From=0, To=1, Duration=200, TransitionOn=Visibility}"
            tz:Transitionz.Translate="{tz:TranslateParams From='10,0', To='0,0', Duration=200, TransitionOn=Visibility}"
            tz:Transitionz.Visibility="{Binding ElementName=CheckBox, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource b2vc}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Which results in this output:

[image]